# Cannot implement Swift SSLCreateContext

Tags: ios, swift, tls1.2, secure-transport

I am new to iOS development, and am trying to implement an SSL connection to a custom port.

I found the code from this answer as the best/easiest implementation of a secure connection over a socket https://stackoverflow.com/a/30733961/2306428

However, I am getting these errors:

`Use of unresolved identifier 'kSSLClientSide'
Use of unresolved identifier 'kSSLStreamType'
Use of unresolved identifier 'kSSLSessionOptionBreakOnClientAuth'`

I have checked and I am running Swift version 2.1.1, using iOS 9.2 SDK and Xcode 7.2. I have even tried adding `import Security` but that has no effect.

What is the reason that these constants are not being found?

The line being tested is here: https://github.com/ksred/bank-ios/blob/master/Bank/TCPClient.swift#L209

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the identifiers declared in Swift:

```
if let sslContext = SSLCreateContext(kCFAllocatorDefault, SSLProtocolSide.ClientSide, SSLConnectionType.StreamType) {
    SSLSetIOFuncs(sslContext, sslReadCallback, sslWriteCallback)
    SSLSetConnection(sslContext, &socketfd)
    SSLSetSessionOption(sslContext, SSLSessionOption.BreakOnClientAuth, true)
    SSLHandshake(sslContext)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the error described in the question.

Comment: Ivan, can you show the definition of sslReadCallback and sslWriteCallback please?  I'm getting errors when I try `func sslReadFunc(conn: SSLConnectionRef, data: UnsafeMutableRawPointer, dataLength: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>) -> OSStatus` for example.