# APNS notification using swift

Tags: php, ios, swift, openssl, apple-push-notifications

iOS 11.x Swift 4.0

Yes, I know there a dozens solutions out there that will send push notifications for you, but I am looking to create a native solution.

Now I managed to put some PHP code together that works, within it I construct a APNS payload and then pack it's way off to Apple, which of course sends it to my client. It is only 10 lines of code, but now I need to convert it to Swift.

```
$payload='{
"aps": {
"alert":{
"title": "Yo",
"body":"Stay Cool" },
"badge":99,
"category":"new.category",
"sound": "default"
},
"misc": "tag"
}';

$apnsHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
$apnsPort = 2195;
$apnsCert = 'apns-dev.pem';
$deviceToken = '7effd4dfc158d922c867c1e3c99fd46296e2b1afcd080a63a2da398bce1c9bb3';
$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$apnsPort = 2195;
$apnsCert = 'apns-dev.pem';
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error,   $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
echo $error;
$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '',     $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
?>
```

I find this answer on SO which looks like my man, but no ... there is no certificate [.pem] on this is there?

[How should Secure Transport TLS be used with BSD sockets in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624738/how-should-secure-transport-tls-be-used-with-bsd-sockets-in-swift/30733961#30733961)

I am out my depth right now? Any help/pointers to the right path desperately needed?

Comment: I didn't get you, you want to send the Push from the client directly?

Comment: Yes; I want to be able to send a push directly from an iOS device.

Comment: It is not the case at all, no need to send push from the client directly you can use HTTP request through the client to send the Push from server-side

Comment: Ok, so I can use NSURL yes? I think I may have found somebody who is already doing so... https://cocoapods.org/pods/APNSwift ?

Comment: Any HTTP request methodology, I prefer to use `Almofire` for Swift as a common library for handling requests